# WebApplicationFactory doesn't (seem to) send out any data

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, azure-application-insights, xunit

I am trying to create an integration test for my ASP.NET Core middleware using the `WebApplicationFactory` type.

My goal is to emulate an ASP.NET Core host, integrate app insights, and actually send data to a real Application Insights instance, to ensure everything is working as expected.

Unfortunately, my test server doesn't send any data to application insights.

This is what my test setup looks like. I have subclassed from `WebApplicationFactory` as follows:

```cs
public class WebTestFixture : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

        builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseEnvironment("Testing");
        });

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config.AddUserSecrets<WebTestFixture>();
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Then the test `Startup` class of my test assembly looks as follows:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        services.AddAppInsightsHttpBodyLogging();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAppInsightsHttpBodyLogging();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapPost("/", async ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from integration test");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The instrumentation key is stored in secrets.json.

```json
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "***HIDDEN***"
  }
}
```

And finally my test

```cs
public class BodyLoggerMiddlewareIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<WebTestFixture>
{
    private readonly WebTestFixture _factory;

    public BodyLoggerMiddlewareIntegrationTests(WebTestFixture factory) => _factory = factory;

    [Fact]
    public async void BodyLoggerMiddleware_Should_Send_And_Mask_Data()
    {
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var requestBody = new
        {
            Name = "Bommelmaier",
            Password = "Abracadabra!",
            AccessToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRJbkFzIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0MjI3Nzk2Mzh9.gzSraSYS8EXBxLN_oWnFSRgCzcmJmMjLiuyu5CSpyHI"
        }; 
        var response = await client.PostAsync("/", new JsonContent(requestBody));

        // Assert
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

The test passes and I can see the following line in the debug log (formatted for better readability), which tells me app insights send out my data.

```
Application Insights Telemetry: 
{
  "name": "AppRequests",
  "time": "2021-12-22T19:13:32.8336126Z",
  "iKey": "***HIDDEN***",
  "tags": {
    "ai.application.ver": "15.0.0.0",
    "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "MY_HOST",
    "ai.operation.id": "3fe600bbe13fcf41b1e52a0df7f7465e",
    "ai.operation.name": "POST /",
    "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "aspnet5c:2.18.0+a9fc6af7538cc287d263d9bc216c7910bfc34566",
    "ai.internal.nodeName": "MY_HOST"
  },
  "data": {
    "baseType": "RequestData",
    "baseData": {
      "ver": 2,
      "id": "3857ad615d298e4b",
      "name": "POST /",
      "duration": "00:00:00.2006790",
      "success": false,
      "responseCode": "400",
      "url": "http://localhost/",
      "properties": {
        "_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors": "(Name:'Requests', Ver:'1.1')",
        "RequestBody": "{\"Name\":\"Bommelmaier\",\"Password\":\"Abracadabra!\",\"AccessToken\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRJbkFzIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0MjI3Nzk2Mzh9.gzSraSYS8EXBxLN_oWnFSRgCzcmJmMjLiuyu5CSpyHI\"}",
        "AspNetCoreEnvironment": "Production",
        "ResponseBody": "Hello from integration test",
        "DeveloperMode": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, nothing ever arrives at my App Insights instance, even after having waited more than 30min. Any idea? What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you open Fiddler and have a look if there is outgoing traffic to the hosts mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses ? Also make sure to allow these hosts/IPs in your outgoing network/firewall/proxy/etc. rules.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Andreas Wendl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5592791/andreas-wendl). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> You can open [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/use-fiddler-everywhere-to-inspect-your-web-traffic) and have a look if there is outgoing traffic to the hosts mentioned here [IP addresses used by Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses)

> Also make sure to allow these hosts/IPs in your outgoing network/firewall/proxy/etc. rules.