# ASP.NET Core WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient does not properly support client side streaming

Tags: asp.net-core, testing, grpc

I am trying to use WebApplicationFactory for end-to-end testing of a system that consists of few a services with gRPC communication between them, implemented via protobuf-net.grpc. My app logic relies on constantly open stream of client requests using via gRPC streaming.

My problem is that WebApplicationFactory 1) somehow prohibits host binding to local ports so I cannot have my apps under test communicate via regular gRPC, and 2) client created using WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient does not send requests to server until the request stream is closed.

Here are more details...

I create service client the following way:

1. Create factory instance: `new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(...)`
2. Create gRPC channel: `channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = factory.CreateClient() })`
3. Create service client: `client = channel.CreateGrpcService<TService>()`

What works:

1. Unary call
2. Client streaming, but server method is being invoked after client closed request stream (in terms of protobuf-net.grpc - the IAsyncEnumerable is exhausted.

Problem: in case client stream never closes, requests never make it to server. Perhaps it is related to the fact that WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient creates HTTP/1.1 client, and streaming requires HTTP/2.

For clarity, this is my simplified client stream implementation which I supply to client method, requestQueue a ConcurrentQueue being filled by a different thread:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<TRequest> Write()
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (requestQueue.TryDequeue(out var request))
        {
            yield return request;
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454306/webapplicationfactory-doesnt-seem-to-send-out-any-data)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my issue is entirely different. gRPC works for unary calls, but fails to call server in case of client side streaming until request stream is closed, even when I generate 10mln requests. That must be related to some special treatment for streaming implemented in WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient which I haven’t figured out yet.

Comment: Looks like this issue may be protobuf.net specific. Have you tried with pure grpc-dotnet and Google.Protobuf?

Comment: If your client ends up using HTTP1.1, the client streaming has no chance of working. It's for the same reason why grpc-web (which uses HTTP1.1) doesn't support client streaming (it only supports server streaming: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#streaming-support ) Simply said, you need http2.0 for the client streaming to work. In fact, you really need http2.0 for grpc protocol in general (if you can't use http2+, you have to use grpc-web).

Comment: I gave up on hosting gRPC server in test process via WebApplicationFactory, streaming simply does not work. I've tried creating HTTP2 client which it allows via customization, still no joy.
I ended up simply starting server as external process, synchronizing my test with it via mutex and accessing it via standard gRPC facilities. Works like a charm, although not as neat. I'd prefer server created via WebApplicationFactory because then I can access its DI container and inspect internal state for "gray box tests".

Comment: @JanTattermusch - I did use both at some point. My understanding is that the problem is not related to protobuf, but either in the way WebApplicationFactory constructs client or the way it wraps server comms. Communication is not going through regular HTTP/TCP stack but rather through something artificial in-process (again, server created this way is not getting bound to local ports), and that artificial communication stack does not support streaming.